# Painting over a texture doesn’t save?

Tags: image, texture-painting

When I paint over an old texture after UV Unwrapping it does not save and if I close the file after saving it is gone. Sorry I couldn't provide a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, You have to save the image before saving the file and closing: you can do it in the UV/image window (Image - Save as image, shortcut F3).